# how to calculate the sample size in rstudio - logistic regression

Tags: r, logistic-regression

How do you calculate the sample size in rstudio. I've seen samples set.seed(1000), set.seed(888), etc. Does it matter based on the number of observations? I found this link [Power and sample size calculations](https://sphweb.bumc.bu.edu/otlt/MPH-Modules/BS/R/R-Manual/R-Manual17.html) but I don't know what the input values needed for the function.

ex. power.t.test(delta=.25,sd=0.7,power=.80)

The input for the function:

n – the sample size in each group

delta – the difference between the means of the two populations

sd – the standard deviation

power – the desired power, as a proportion (between 0 and 1)

Comment: Seed is not the sample size, it is the seed for the "random" number generator, which is entirely not random. The results are distributed approximately randomly but are a set sequence based on the seed you start from. The reason folks give a seed is so that others can reproduce the same results as them.

Answer (score 1):

The link in the question points to power calculation of the **t.test**, but the question asks about **logistic** regression. Furthermore `ex.power.t.test` seems to be also for the t-test, not a GLM.

There are in general two methods for power analysis:

1. deterministic estimation with method-specific formulae, often with an optimization step
2. simulation with a given method and a certain number of trials, e.g. 1000. In the latter case, sample size matters and also somewhat the initialisation of the random number generator, specified with `set.seed`.

One can easily set up a simulation yourself with a little bit programming.

On the other hand, power analysis for GLMs and other models is readily available in function `pwr.f2.test` from package **pwr**. According to the help file:

"Exactly one of the parameters 'u','v','f2','power' and 'sig.level' must be passed as NULL, and that parameter is determined from the others. Notice that the last one has non-NULL default so NULL must be explicitly passed if you want to compute it."

This is the example from the documentation:

```
pwr.f2.test(u=5,v=89,f2=0.1/(1-0.1),sig.level=0.05)
```

But if you instead want to calculate the significance level from the power, use:

```
pwr.f2.test(u=5, v=89, f2=0.1/(1-0.1), sig.level=NULL, power=0.8)
```

More details can be found in the documentation, especially in the [package vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pwr/vignettes/pwr-vignette.html).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you both. I misunderstood the link reference. n in set.seed(n) is just a random number. It shouldn't be set/reset to another random number too often. It's specified so others can reproduce the same results. It doesn't seem to be based on the number of observations or anything else.